# How to update a MySql field based upon value of another field in the same record

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update values in a MySQL table and really getting stuck.

Basically I want to update a column's value to 1 where another column (in the same row) = "N".  It should be quite simple but I can't fathom it.

```
UPDATE household SET allowsDogs=1 WHERE allowsCats="N"
```

In my mind the above query should, for each household if allowsCats="N" then set allowsDogs to 1. But instead I get an empty result set.

I have also tried variations:

```
Update household  set allowsDogs=1 where householdID in (select householdID from household where allowsCats="N") 

Update household  set allowsDogs=1 where householdID in (select householdID from copy_of_household where copy_of_household.allowsCats="N")
```

I'm just about to write a php script to read in each row and update one at a time....But there must be an easier way...

Comment: Try this:  Select * from household where allowsCats = "N".  I assume you will get an empty set, which is why no rows are being updated.

Comment: What result set do you get for **select householdID from household where allowsCats="N"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you have specified is correct, and should work.  I believe this is where you are getting tripped up:

> But instead I get an empty result set.

`UPDATE` queries do not return any result set.  They do their work and then return an empty result set.  However, your client library or application should provide a way for you to see *how many* records were altered (but not which specific ones).

Further, note that the database server may skip updating a record if all of the fields you are updating already have the new value you are assigning.  For example, if all of the records in the table with the field `allowCats` equal to `"N"` also have their `allowDogs` field equal to `1` then the database server may not include those rows in the total number of rows updated, since they were not actually changed.

Comment: Aggh! I don't believe it!  The reason that I was getting 0 records updated was because the rows already had the correct values. @cdhowie your "Further note" was bang on correct! Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you mean one of the following:

```
UPDATE household
    SET allowsDogs = 1
    WHERE allowsCats = 0;
```

or

```
UPDATE household
    SET allowsDogs = 'Y'
    WHERE allowsCats = 'N';
```

Mixing numbers and characters for flags is like, well, mixing cats and dogs.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I have sorted it now.  FYI - I am converting my char-based indexes to tinyint in the hope to optimize a bit.  Hence the mixed data types.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is correct, but it should not return result set.

To see the result use separate `SELECT * FROM household` statement.